# Django ORM: calculation only inside databse-query possible?

Tags: django, database, orm

I have rather simple dataset that's containing the following data:

```
id    |    aqi    |    date          |    state_name
1     |    17     |    2020-01-01    |    California
2     |    54     |    2020-01-02    |    California
3     |    37     |    2020-01-03    |    California
4     |    29     |    2020-01-04    |    California
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the average aqi (air-quality-index) from april 2022 minus the average aqi from april 2021, without using multiple queries. Is this even possible or should I use two queries and compare them manually?
From my understanding, I should use the Q-Expression to filter the correct dates, correct?

```
AirQuality.objects.filter(Q(date__range=['2021-04-01', '2021-04-30']) & Q('2022-04-01', '2022-04-30'))
```

The best solution I came across myself so far is:

```py
qs_apr20 = (
    AirQuality.objects
    .aggregate(apr20=Avg('aqi', filter=Q(date__range=(datetime.date(2020, 4, 1), datetime.date(2020, 4, 30)))))['apr20']
)

qs_apr21 = (
    AirQuality.objects
    .aggregate(apr21=Avg('aqi', filter=Q(date__range=(datetime.date(2021, 4, 1), datetime.date(2021, 4, 30)))))['apr21']
)

result = round(qs_apr21 - qs_apr20, 2)
```

Thanks for your help and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Inspiring from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet), the following should work:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from django.db.models import Q, Avg
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> apr21 = Avg('aqi', filter=Q(date__range=(datetime.date(2021, 4, 1), datetime.date(2021, 4, 30)))
>>> apr22 = Avg('aqi', filter=Q(date__range=(datetime.date(2022, 4, 1), datetime.date(2022, 4, 30)))
>>> aqi_calc = Airquality.objects.annotate(apr21=apr21)
                         .annotate(apr22=apr22)
                         .annotate(diff=F('apr22') - F('apr21'))
```

It should do everything in 1 query, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Not quite...when executing the query, I still receive single row from the original data. What I'm trying to achieve is getting back a single number - or let's say a dictionary, like inside a aggregation.